# Adjusting D3 Chart Bar Height

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js, data-visualization, bar-chart

I'm putting together a D3 vertical bar chart and can't adjust the bar's height.  When I adjust the `barHeight` variable from the following javascript, when rendered the bar's look exactly the same.  Meaning if I took off the `*50` in `barHeight` nothing would change.  I'm probably overlooking something really really simple here, but how do I adjust the height?

```
  var bars = svg.selectAll("rect")
     .data(data_votes);
     bars.enter()
     .append("rect")
     // .transition()
     //   .duration(1000);

     bars.attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return i * (w / data_votes.length); 

     })
     .attr("y", function(d){
        return h-d; 
     })
     // Less bars == more width
     .attr("width", w / data_votes.length - barPadding)
     .attr("height", function(d){
        var barHeight = d*50; 
        return barHeight; 
     })

     .attr("fill", "teal");

     bars.exit().remove();
```

Comment: Is `data_votes` actually an array or numbers? If it's not –– i.e. if it's an array of Objects –– that'll certainly not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example with some corrected code:

**And a very good example of why links to other sites that don't include the code are a bad idea.  Tributary.io is not responding in December of 2019.**

http://tributary.io/inlet/5767993
(You can click on any number and change it with the slider to see it's effect on the output)

I think the main issue was that the scale factor needed to be applied to both the "y" attribute and the height attribute.

Comment: If you want a fixed scale (with the max value always being 200 px, for instance) you need to use a d3 scale (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear-scales) I will update the tributary code to use one of those so you can see how it works.

Comment: No problem. See http://tributary.io/inlet/5768111 for an example using the linear scale.

Comment: Whoops, i ahd forgotten to save after i made the final edits. http://tributary.io/inlet/5768111 works now

Answer (score 0):

You're right, I was adjusting the offset with the height so while the height pixel was actually increasing, it was offset proportionally and hidden off the edge of the svg canvas.

Here's how I adjusted it

```
 .attr("y", function(d){
    return h-(d*4); 
 })
 // Less bars == more width
 .attr("width", w / data_votes.length - barPadding)
 .attr("height", function(d) {
    return d * 4 ;

 })
```